# Change all border colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change all border colors on the current page once a button is clicked. I do this by toggling a class and define that class in CSS.

```js
    var all = document.querySelector("*")
    
    changeBorder = function() {
        all.classList.toggle("border");
    }
```

```css
    *.border {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: green;
    }
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <button onclick="changeBorder()">Change the borders</button>
    
    <div>Border</div>
    <div>Border</div>
    <div>Border</div>
    <div>Border</div>
    <div>Border</div>
```

The code above does not work as it applies a border to everything on the page, and removing the "border-style" will make the code invalid.

Comment: *removing the "border-style" will make the code invalid.* --> it's actually what you need to do to make sure only the element that have a border will get the color changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to avoid `on` HTML attributes to invoke functions, instead use a selector with `addEventListener`

---

Here is a basic code to do what you're trying to achieve by using `classList` inside a loop `forEach`

```js
//short version
document.querySelector('.js-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('red')))

//regular version
//document.querySelector('.js-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
//  document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach((el) => {
//    el.classList.toggle('red')
//  })
//})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.red {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<button class='js-toggle'>Change the borders</button>

<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
```

If you really want to select all the elements to change border, you can use the wildcard selector `*`

```js
//short version
document.querySelector('.js-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('red')))

//regular version
//document.querySelector('.js-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
//  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((el) => {
//    el.classList.toggle('red')
//  })
//})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black
}

.red {
  border-color: red
}
```

```html
<button class='js-toggle'>Change the borders</button>

<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401743/why-did-this-performance-question-warrant-not-only-closure-but-deletion-too

Answer (score 2):

```html
<button onclick="changeBorder()">Change the borders</button>

<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>

<style>
    *.border {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: green;
    }
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>
<script>
    // var all = document.querySelector("*"); we should select the divs, not everything.
    var all = document.querySelectorAll("div");

    changeBorder = function () {
        // all.classList.toggle("border"); we should loop through the array of divs. 
        for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
            all[i].classList.toggle("border");
        }
    };
</script>
```

So

1. I changed `querySelector` with `querySelectorAll`
2. I changed the target from everything to only divs: `querySelectorAll("div")`
3. I looped through the array and toggled the class of each of the divs

Comment: Only points because the code works. This is not how I would code. Separate your HTML from your JavaScript. It will save you many a keystroke and is far more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var all = document.querySelectorAll("*")

changeBorder = function() {
    all.forEach(item =>{
        item.classList.toggle("border");
    })
}
```

```css
*.border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeBorder()">Change the borders</button>

<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
<div>Border</div>
```